# Yeoman generator not outputting anything

Tags: command-line-interface, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I am trying to write a very basic generator that will create 4 files relevant to a component. All the generator need do at this point is take in a component name from the command line and in turn, create 4 files with that name. The generator runs fine but doesn't do anything upon completion.

my `index.js` inside `/app`

```
'use strict';
//Require dependencies
var chalk = require('chalk');
var yosay = require('yosay');
var Generator = require('yeoman-generator');

module.exports = class extends Generator {
    prompting() {
      var done = this.async();
      this.prompt({
        type: 'input',
        name: 'componentName',
        message: 'Your component name',
        default: this.appname
      }, (answers) => {
        this.props = answers
      });
    }

    writing() {
        const componentName = this.props.componentName;

        this.fs.copyTpl(
            `${this.templatePath()}/**/!(_)*`,
            this.destinationPath(),
            this.props
        );

        this.fs.copyTpl(
            this.templatePath('src/_component.js'),
            this.destinationPath(`${componentName}.js`),
            this.props
        );

        this.fs.copyTpl(
            this.templatePath('src/_component.spec.js'),
            this.destinationPath(`${componentName}.spec.js`),
            this.props
        );

        this.fs.copyTpl(
            this.templatePath('src/_component.scss'),
            this.destinationPath(`${componentName}.scss`),
            this.props
        );

        this.fs.copyTpl(
            this.templatePath('src/_component.pug'),
            this.destinationPath(`${componentName}.pug`),
            this.props
        );
    }

    install() {
        this.installDependencies();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To output content use `this.log("your message")`. You can use it in `end()` function to inform user that generation is competed